# Match a character only when not in a quoted field or in between 2 quotes

Tags: regex, perl

Consider the following character strings:

```
"bla ; bla"; bla
"bla "";"" bla"; bla
"bla ";" bla"; bla
```

I'm trying to match any `;` that is not in a quoted field (e.g. `"bla ; bla"`) or in between 2 quotes.

In other words, I would like to match the second `;` in the first 2 strings and all `;` in the last string.

Here are the 2 regex I've been trying but I can't manage to make one that works in all cases.

```
^(['"])(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?=;)(*SKIP)(*F)|;
^(['"])(?:(?!(?!\1)\1).)*\1(?=;)(*SKIP)(*F)|;
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I omitted several important details in my initial question. The example lines above are from `.csv` files. I'm trying to extract all file separators `;` in lines from different files. The problem I have is to distinguish between a quoted `;` inside a quoted field (line 2) and two quoted fields separated by `;` (line 3). A quoted field is always followed by `;` in my case.

Comment: `Text::ParseWords` is pretty good at this. If it is proper csv, you might even use `Text::CSV`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```perl
(?:"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*')(?<!;["'])(*SKIP)(*F)|;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zN92xz/3). *Details*:

- `(?:"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*')` - a non-capturing group matching either

  - `"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"` - a `"`, then any zero or more chars other than a `"` char, then zero or more occurrences of a `""` string and then any zero or more chars other than a `"` char, and then a `"` again
  - `|` - or
  - `'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'` - a `'`, then any zero or more chars other than a `'` char, then zero or more occurrences of a `''` string and then any zero or more chars other than a `'` char, and then a `'` again
- `(?<!;["'])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `;` and `'` or `"` immediately to the left of the current location
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - fail the match and start the search for the next match from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `;` - a semi-colon.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Your regex simplifies mine a lot. That said, I reckon I was not precise enough in my question. The part of the character string I consider a sentence has to be followed by a `;`.  Hence the `(?=;)` in my regex. For example, in this character string `"bla ;" bla"; bla`, I would like to match all `;`.

Comment: @Junitar What semi-colons need matching in `";bla ;" bla"; bla`? Also, all of them? If all of them, use `(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')(?<!;["'])(*SKIP)(*F)|;`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zN92xz/2).

Comment: In fact, my examples are lines from a `.csv` files. I'm trying to extract all file separators in  lines from some files. I should have said it my question to avoid any confusions. Your example technically cannot happen, it would have to be `"";bla ;" bla"; bla` or `";bla ;"" bla"; bla` to be valid and in that case I would like to match all `;` in the 1st case and only the last in the 2nd case. If quoted, a field cannot contain only one quote of the same kind of the field quotes (line 2 in my question). I'm struggling making the distinction between that case and several quoted fields (line 3).

Comment: This looks like an XY-problem. Maybe you'd better use a module that handles CSV files.

Comment: So, try `(?:"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*')(?<!;["'])(*SKIP)(*F)|;`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zN92xz/3).

Answer (score 5):

Use an actual CSV parser (Well, Semicolon-SV) like `Text::CSV_XS` instead of trying to hack up something with regular expressions:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, sep_char => ";"});

while (my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA)) {
    say $row->[0];
}


__DATA__
"bla ; bla"; bla
"bla "";"" bla"; bla
"bla ";" bla"; bla
```

Comment: That might indeed be the best solution. I needed a quick fix for my problem and a regex like the one suggested by @Wiktor Stribiżew works well in my case. I will surely implement an actual parser when I have time.

Comment: @Junitar It not only is a better solution, it is the easiest. Your strange regexes is the hard and time consuming solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest (AFAIK shortest) and widely supported (doesn’t use `SKIP`, which isn’t commonly supported):

```
(?<!"");(?!"")(?=((?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/dicXzRHShWFQrQ).

It works by using look arounds to assert:

- not wrapped in double quotes
- followed by an even number (including zero) of quotes

Comment: SKIP was added in perl 5.10 back in 2007... granted, you still sometimes see people stuck on 5.8 (Or even older, poor souls), but it's certainly widely supported these days.

Comment: @Shawn OK, but the question (and this answer) in general may be of help to java or similar language users whose regex engine does not support SKIP.